# Can I automate saving different combinations of layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows, photoshop-scripting

I have a source file for an icon. It has a base layer which is the icon background, and a number of layer folders, each of which contains layers for each individual icon. There are 20 or so of these folders. To save the icon set, I need to:

1. Make the base layer visible, and hide all other layers
2. Show the folder of the icon I want to save
3. Save the file, with an appropriate name (the name of the folder)
4. Hide that folder.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 for every folder

I've played around with the scripting in Photoshop but haven't been able to make something that does this automatically (it's an annoyingly time-consuming operation). Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplication of this http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5578/how-to-extract-individual-elements-from-a-psd-without-much-effort

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! Here's what you do. Open the **Layer Comps** window in photoshop. Click the **snapshot** button, hide your current layer, show the next layer, click the snapshot again. Create a layer comp snapshot for each state of your document that you want to have exported as individual files. Once you have all of those ready, go to **File > Scripts > Layer Comps to Files**. Set up your destinate folder and image settings, then export and you will have all of those layer comps as single images.

Comment: In newer versions of PS (CC 2017), its **File > Export > Layer Comps to Files...**.

Answer (score 4):

[Photoshop Composition Composer](https://github.com/mechanicious/photoshopCompositionComposer) will do just what you need. In your case use only a single top-level folder.

### Usage

1. See the Example and the Preview below to learn how it works
2. Download and unzip `photoshopCompositionComposer` `jsx`-file
3. Open your project and navigate to `File > Scripts > Browse...`
4. Browse and load the downloaded `jsx` file

Note: use prefix `__` (double underscore) for top-level group names to exclude groups from the composition composing process. E.g. `__ignoreThisGroup`

### Example

**Layers**

[image]

**Resulting Compositions**

[image]
[image]